# TFS all work items are disappeared after a windows' date change

Tags: tfs, storyboard

The date of Team foundation server changed *to the year: 2023* and after that non of the defined work items can be found at the board. Neither they're accessible by querying. As it seems they're lost for only a certain project. All of the other projects are alright.

They didn't appear even after correction of the date.

How can I get the disappeared work items back?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Could not reproduce your issue with same steps on TFS2017. Besides, is there anything special about that project?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the work items not only in VS but also through web portal.

If you could also not find the work item by entering a known Work Item Id. Suggest you remote to your TFS database server and launched SQL Server Management Studio to explore the raw data. Double check if the workitems  are still stored in database.

If not you may have to restore your last back-up TFS database. Otherwise suggest you [clear TFS and VS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/).